# response not being written using filter and ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, stream, servlet-filters

I have the following filter:

```
@WebFilter( filterName = "myfilter" )
public class WebCacheFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init( FilterConfig filterConfig ) {}

    @EJB
    AppExceptionLogger logger;

    @Override
    public void doFilter( ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain )
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest request = ( HttpServletRequest )req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = ( HttpServletResponse )res;
        execute( new StreamAction<ByteArrayOutputStream>() {
            @Override
            public void doAction( ByteArrayOutputStream stream ) throws Exception {
                chain.doFilter( request, new ProxiedServletResponse( response, stream ) );
                response.getOutputStream()
                    .write( stream.toByteArray() );
            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    private void execute( StreamAction<ByteArrayOutputStream> action ) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            action.doAction( stream );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            logger.logInternal( e );
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

being mappend in web.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

ProxiedServletResponse class is from here: https://github.com/FagnerMartinsBrack/Servlet-GZIP-Compression/blob/95f4bac01e5037ea403f502819d3e74f66ef1ad0/src/main/java/com/fagnerbrack/servlet/gzip/proxy/ProxiedServletResponse.java

Below is the `test.jsp` file content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Página de teste</title>
    <!-- Descrição do sistema -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- Ajusta o conteúdo de acordo com o tamanho da tela em aparelhos mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    test page
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to access a `\webapp\test.jsp` file the browser does not print anything. It seems the `response.getOutputStream().write( stream.toByteArray() );` part is not working. Why is that?

**Note:** If you try to access a javascript file like `/static/js/jquery.js` it loads correctly. Only the JSP files are not loading.

**Note2:** In the `baos.toByteArray()` part the ByteArrayOutputStream has a length of 0 for JSP files (!!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSPs write to `getWriter()`, not `getOutputStream()`. In your `getWriter()`, you're wrapping the `ByteArrayInputStream` in a `PrintWriter`. The `PrintWriter` has a 8K chars buffer. The JSP is clearly smaller than 8K chars. You're never `flush()`ing the buffer of `PrintWriter` before obtaining the written `byte[]`, so it never writes to the wrapped `ByteArrayInputStream`.

You need to flush the bitch. Replace

```
chain.doFilter(request, new ProxiedServletResponse(response, stream));
response.getOutputStream().write(stream.toByteArray());
```

by

```
HttpServletResponse proxiedResponse = new ProxiedServletResponse(response, stream);
chain.doFilter(request, proxiedResponse);
proxiedResponse.flushBuffer();
response.getOutputStream().write(stream.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Is this sh1t simplified in Java 8?

Comment: This part, no. I do however wonder how `execute` and `StreamAction` in your snippet are useful here.

Comment: Yeah I realized I did not needed to close the stream since it is created by me and used only in this filter lifecycle. In some circumstances I use that execute/action pattern for closing streams instead of using try-with-resource.